# How to handle common elements in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Just started with jquery mobile andI understand the notion of data-role page.
My app will consist of single pages instead of multiple ones within one HTML file

These pages, when rendered as a traditional website, contain a lot of common markup (header, menu, footer)
Ideally, I would like each new page to just modify the content of the page and not load all of the extra markup.
This I can handle just fine server side and return just the HTML fragment without the rest of the elements.
However, jqm will display only the response and all common bits are hidden.
Someone could argue, to just return everything, but some of the common elements (the menu for instance)
has client side logic which makes an AJAX request upon page load to display user specific data and there is no need to do this for every page.

I believe this to be a very common scenario and I am interested in how you all have dealt with this
situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the latest JQM 1.4 [demos](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/). Header, Footer, Panels and Popup can be created outside of a JQM page, so the only thing left is

```
 <div data-role="page" id="your_page_id">
    <div class="ui-content">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Only the page with content will change on changePage calls. The rest will persist.

**NOTE**: Be sure to call

```
 $(document).enhanceWithin()
```

before showing your page, because JQM will not enhance elements outside of a page afaik.

Comment: Thanks. I see that 1.4 is in alpha however. Looking for a stable version solution. Also I could not find any examples with what you descibe. Do you have a direct link?

Comment: and what you are looking works quite well, because I'm currently using it, too.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I do not see anything there similar with what I describe. Am I missing something. Sorry for this back and forth

Comment: The link was just for the latest JQM files. Here is one with everything outside a page - [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/617). There are still some minor bugs, but should be fixed before 1.4 is out I hope.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look

Comment: I checked it and it works. However, the panel has some issues when viewed in a mobile device. Specifically, when you swipe left to close it, the whole page scrolls instead of the panel hiding. Do you know if this is a known bug?

Comment: not sure, there are some bugs which are being worked on for 1.4 ([here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6604)) and panels outside of pages. So if you think it is a bug, file an issue on [Git](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues?state=open)